# Retrieving the package name of the app which binds to my service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, package-name

I have an android Service in my app which external apps can bind to. Also, when an app binds to my service I return a `Messenger` for them to use for communicating with my service. This is kinda what it looks like

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new MyHandler());

    @Overide
    onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

One requirement I have is to find out the package name of the app that bound to my Service. But after looking around it almost seems like there's no way to get that. I couldn't find any useful methods either in the `Intent` used to bind to my service, or in the `Messenger` used when communicating with my service.

Is there any way to get the package name of the connecting app?